# Order of the views in Query database and Views in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, view, controller

The order of the views change wen i make a call to a database. In this case i make a Formulari.php that is a Controller.

**Formulari.php**

```
    public function resum(){

        **$this->load->view('header');**

        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tarifes");

            # code...
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
            echo $row['operador'];
            echo $row['minutatge'];
            echo $row['permanencia'];
            echo $row['dades'];
            echo $row['preu'];
            echo '</br>';
        }

        $this->load->view('resum_taula');
        $this->load->view('footer');

    }
```

When I see this controller the first i can see is the table that returns me. But que first view i want to see is the title.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Create a proper model function first would be best http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html

Answer (score 0):

Controller

```
$data['formular_data'] = $this->your_model->getData();

$this->load->view('resum_taula', $data);
$this->load->view('footer');
```

Model

```
function getData() {
    $query = $this->db->get('tarifes');
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

View

```
<?php print_r($formular_data'); ?> //  form $data['formular_data'];
```